# Ajax form not posting in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a form that uploads a file with a specified name and category.  I have it set so use the post on page using the ajax.beginform call.  When I click submit it doesn't do anything but redirect to the page.

Form:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AttachFile", "Attachments", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "filesuccess", OnSuccess = "addFileSuccess", OnFailure = "addFileFailure" }, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            <div class="modal-body" id="addfilemodaltext">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="control-label">Select file to add to this collaboration:</div>
                    @Html.Hidden("CollaborationId", Model.Collaboration.Id)
                    <input type="file" name="FileContents" id="FileContents"/>                        
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="control-label">Enter a description for this file: </div>
                    @Html.TextArea("FileDescription", null, new {@class = "form-control"})
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="control-label">Select a Category for this file:</div>
                    @Html.DropDownList("categoryId", new SelectList(Model.AttachmentCategories, "Id", "Name"), new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="addfilebtn" value="Upload File" />
            </div>
        }
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AttachFile(int CollaborationId, string FileDescription, int categoryId, HttpPostedFileBase FileContents)
    {
        if (FileContents != null && FileContents.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var fileName = FileContents.FileName;
            var mimeType = FileContents.ContentType;                
            var fileLength = FileContents.ContentLength;
            byte[] fileData = new byte[fileLength];
            FileContents.InputStream.Read(fileData, 0, fileLength);

            var response = DchServiceUtility.ServiceClient.AddAttachmentToCollaboration(CollaborationId,
                CurrentUser.Id, mimeType, FileDescription, fileName, fileData, categoryId, AppSettings.ClientName);

        }

        return RedirectToAction("Details", "Collaborations", new { @id = CollaborationId });
    }
```

One thing new is that it started to not be able to resolve action "AttachFile".  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Redirect to what page? Where is this view placed? Do you have jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js referenced?

Comment: Yes, where the view is placed. Yes i have the js referenced

Comment: Is this view returned from the same controller as 'AttachFile' action?

Comment: the view returned is not in the same controller.

Comment: Perhaps the [HttpPost] attribute is missing above the controller action

Comment: I have the httppost on there, basically when i click submit, it shows the onsuccess but doesn't upload the file

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add enctype attribute like this:

```
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("YourAction", "YourController",
                    new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST", //More options here },
                    new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
```

**Edit**: Your code with hardcoded `categoryId` and `CollaborationId`

```
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AttachFile", "Home", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "filesuccess", OnSuccess = "addFileSuccess", OnFailure = "addFileFailure" }, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
    <div class="modal-body" id="addfilemodaltext">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="control-label">Select file to add to this collaboration:</div>
            @Html.Hidden("CollaborationId", 1)
            <input type="file" name="FileContents" id="FileContents" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="control-label">Enter a description for this file: </div>
            @Html.TextArea("FileDescription", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="control-label">Select a Category for this file:</div>
             @Html.Hidden("categoryId", 1)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="addfilebtn" value="Upload File" />
    </div>
    }
```

**Result:**
[image]

Comment: I've updated my code to include what I currently have

Comment: I've tested your code and works fine. The only changes I've made was to hardcode the `CollaborationId` and `categoryId`